# What is .done in Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm learning JS Promise and I noticed some code examples using `Promise` is that they append `.done` at the end. I've checked the [Promise api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) but couldn't find any information about it. My assumption is that it works like `finally` in a `try...catch` statement wherein it gets called no matter what the Promise returns. I've been searching everywhere but couldn't find an answer.

So my question is, is it built in with Promise, what does it basically do?

#### Follow Up Question

If `.done()` doesn't exist in vanilla JS, is there a way to mimic this "catch-all" function?

#### EDIT

Sorry my bad this isn't included in ES6 Promise spec so I'm removing the ES6 tag.

Comment: Are you sure it's ES6 Promise?

Comment: If it's not in the promise API I'm inclined to say you don't need it or it doesn't exist.

Comment: The [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) spec doesn't include a `.done()` method. On the JavaScript `Promise.prototype` object there are "then" and "catch" methods, but no "done". The jQuery Promise implementation, which wasn't Promises/A+ compliant until 3.0 (I think), had a "done" method, but that wasn't ES2015.

Comment: "some of the code examples" — Which code examples?

Comment: This really depends on the library that you're using and the examples that you see. Often, it's a catch-all for your Promise chain completing, but it depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few promise libraries have a `.done()` method whose main purpose is to catch and rethrow any errors that were not handled, so that they show up in the console (in browsers) or crash the process in Node. I suspect this is why you are seeing it at the end of promise chains so often.

In Q and bluebird, it accepts fulfilled and rejection handlers, but since it returns `undefined`, it can't be chained further than that. The bluebird documentation discourages its use and says it's only present for historical purposes because bluebird provides more graceful ways to deal with unhandled errors.

From [the Q documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress):

> Much like then, but with different behavior around unhandled rejection. If there is an unhandled rejection, either because promise is rejected and no onRejected callback was provided, or because onFulfilled or onRejected threw an error or returned a rejected promise, the resulting rejection reason is thrown as an exception in a future turn of the event loop.
>
> This method should be used to terminate chains of promises that will not be passed elsewhere. Since exceptions thrown in then callbacks are consumed and transformed into rejections, exceptions at the end of the chain are easy to accidentally, silently ignore. By arranging for the exception to be thrown in a future turn of the event loop, so that it won't be caught, it causes an onerror event on the browser window, or an uncaughtException event on Node.js's process object.
>
> Exceptions thrown by done will have long stack traces, if Q.longStackSupport is set to true. If Q.onerror is set, exceptions will be delivered there instead of thrown in a future turn.
>
> The Golden Rule of done vs. then usage is: either return your promise to someone else, or if the chain ends with you, call done to terminate it. Terminating with catch is not sufficient because the catch handler may itself throw an error.

Re: Is there a way to mimic this catch-all function?

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
if (!Promise.prototype.done) {
    Promise.prototype.done = function (onfulfilled, onrejected, onprogress) {
        this.then(onfulfilled, onrejected, onprogress)
            .catch(function (error) {
                setTimeout(function () { throw error; }, 0);
            });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking at a jQuery [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) example, you may see examples using [done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

If you're looking at a [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) example, you may see examples using [done](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/done.html).

I am certain there are other libraries that expose `.done()` as part of their promise API, but it's important to be aware that this is **not** compatible with Promises/A+ and is typically added as an enhancement.

This also means that there's no way I can adequately tell you what `.done()` will do, as it will depend entirely on the library that's being used for the exact implementation.

---

Another jQuery-specific note: jQuery's Deferred implementation predated the Promises/A+ specification, and so the majority of the library was not A+ compatible until jQuery v3.

Comment: I was typing up this exact response. Many libraries add `done` as a part of their API (as a convenience, sugar, or, in the case of jQuery, because they sort of built their own take), but it isn't part of the official specification.

Comment: @downvoter care to comment on which part of this answer is not useful or incorrect?